# Event bubbling with querySelector

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener attached to a container, and I'm wanting to filter what is being clicked.

In the example below I'm filtering out `UL.head` clicks.

```
<div>
 <ul class="head">
  <li data-test="...">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="head">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li data-test="...">3</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="head">
  <li>1</li>
  <li data-test="...">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
 </ul>
</div>

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  var ul = findParentByClass(e.target, ".head");
  if(ul) { // clicke a UL }

});

function findParentByClass(node, cls) {
    while (node && !hasClass(node, cls)) {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return node;
}
```

I'm wanting to reproduce a similar function to the `findParentByClass`, but it would be `findParentByQuerySelector`. So I could do something like:

```
li = findParentByQuerySelector('li:[data-test]');
if(li) { // clicked li with data-test attribute }
```

I'm stumped as to how I could implement a `querySelector` into this event bubbling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) method:

```
function findParentBySelector(node, selector) {
    while (node && !node.matches(selector)) {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return node;
}
```

However, do note that implementation of this method is unfortunately inconsistent.

Alternatively, you could use the more-common [`Element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), which matches against the specified element's children. This does mean you need to consider grandparents as well as parents:

```
function findParentBySelector(node, selector) {
    while (node && node.parentNode) {
        let list = node.parentNode.querySelectorAll(selector);
        if (Array.prototype.includes.call(list, node)) {
          return node
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return node;
}
```

But I wouldn't exactly call that method pretty.

Comment: How is it inconsistent?

Comment: @ditto read the documentation I linked; not all browsers implement this, and some implement it under a different name

Comment: @ditto It was initially implemented with vendor prefixes, `mozMatchesSelector`,  `msMatchesSelector`, `oMatchesSelector`, `webkitMatchesSelector`. You could normalize behavior with this polyfill https://gist.github.com/elijahmanor/6452535